# syntax error near unexpected token `else' error

Tags: shell

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
. ~/.profile
exec &> /export/home/oracle/scripts/Test_OHS_status.log
/opt/app/oracle/Middleware/Oracle_WT1/instances/instance1/bin/opmnctl status
chmod 777 /export/home/oracle/scripts/Test_OHS_status.log
if [ -f /export/home/oracle/scripts/Test_OHS_status.log ] ; then
cp /export/home/oracle/scripts/Test_OHS_status.log /home/sedward
chmod 777 /home/sedward/Test_OHS_status.log
grep "[Alive, Down]" /home/sedward/Test_OHS_status.log | mailx -s "Test - OHS Status" steven10@gmail.com < /home/sedward/Test_OHS_status.log
fi
else
echo "something wrong with Test OHS" | cat >> /home/sedward/Test_OHS_status.log | mailx -s "check if oracle HTTP server is up on Test" steven10@gmail.com < /home/sedward/Test_OHS_status.log
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not for debugging. That's what the chats are for!

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the error message, you have a syntax error.

You close your `if` block and then try to use an `else` block:

```
...
fi
else
...
```

The `else` needs to be part of the `if` block:

```
if ... then
...
else
...
fi
```